# Proving the uniqness of the minimizer

Tags: real-analysis

I consider der function $ F:\ \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n  $ with $ F(x)=\|A\cdot x-b\|_2^2+\lambda \cdot \|x\|_2^2 $.

At first it is $$ \begin{align} F(x)&=\|A\cdot x-b\|_2^2+\lambda \cdot \|x\|_2^2\\&=(x^T\cdot A^T-b^T)\cdot (A\cdot x-b)+\lambda\cdot x^T\cdot x. \end{align}$$

Each component of $ \nabla F(x) $ is $$ \begin{align}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x)&=e_i^T\cdot A^T\cdot (A\cdot x-b)+(x^T\cdot A^T-b^T)\cdot A\cdot e_i+\lambda\cdot e_i^T\cdot x+\lambda\cdot x^T\cdot e_i\\&=2\cdot (e_i^T\cdot A^T\cdot (A\cdot x-b)+\lambda \cdot e_i^T\cdot x),\quad i=1,...,n. \end{align}$$
So it is
$$ \nabla F(x)=2\cdot (A^T\cdot (A\cdot x-b)+\lambda\cdot x)=2\cdot ((A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n)\cdot x-A^T\cdot b)\stackrel{!}{=}\textbf{0}\in \mathbb{R}^n. $$

Now I want to show that $$ (A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n)\cdot x=A^T\cdot b $$

has an unique solution which means that $ A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n $ invertible.

I tried two ways:

1.) $ A^T\cdot A $ is symmetric, so it can be
diagonalized it with orhtogonal transformation matrix $ S\in \mathcal{O}(n) $ such that $ A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n=S\cdot D\cdot S^T+\lambda\cdot S\cdot S^T=S\cdot (D+\lambda\cdot I_n)\cdot S^T $.
We have $ \underbrace{\det(S)}_{\neq 0}\cdot \underbrace{\det(D+\lambda\cdot I_n)}_{=?} \cdot \underbrace{\det(S^T)}_{\neq 0}. $
The problem is now whether $ D+\lambda\cdot I_n $ is always invertible which I cannot see here.

2.) Suppose $ A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n $ is not invertible. Then this matrix has the eigenvalue $ \mu=0 $. Let without loss of generality $ \omega $ be an eigenvalue of $ A^T\cdot A $ with an eigenvector $ v\neq 0 $ such that $ \mu=\omega+\lambda=0 $. We get
$ (A^T\cdot A+\lambda\cdot I_n)\cdot v=A^T\cdot A\cdot v+\lambda\cdot I_n\cdot v=(\omega+\lambda)\cdot v=\mu\cdot v=0\cdot v=0 $. In this case it is $ \lambda=-\omega $ and because of $ \lambda>0 $ the eigenvalue $ 
\omega $ is stricktly negative. Then $ A^T\cdot A $ is not positive definite.

I get stuck in both ideas and I cannot found annother way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is correct: you show that if $A^\top A + \lambda I_n$ is not invertible, then $A^\top A$ has a strictly negative eigenvalue. But this is a contradiction since $A^\top A$ is positive semidefinite.

Explicitly: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^\top A$ with negative eigenvalue $\omega$, then $v^\top A^\top A v = \omega \|v\|^2 < 0$ while $v^\top A^\top A v = \|Av\|^2 \ge 0$, a contradiction.

---

Your first approach can also be salvaged. $D + \lambda I_n$ is a diagonal matrix, where the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ appear in the diagonal entries of $D$. Since $A^\top A$ is positive semi-definite, the diagonal entries of $D$ are nonnegative. Since $\lambda$ is strictly positive, the diagonal entries of $D + \lambda I_n$ are also strictly positive, so $D + \lambda I_n$ is invertible.